# How to make Django's devserver public ? Is it generally possible?

Tags: python, django, devserver

I'm currently trying out the Django framework and I would share/present/show some stuff I've made to my workmate/friends. I work in Ubuntu under Win7 via VMware. So my wish/desire is to  send my current pub-IP with port (e.g http://123.123.123.123:8181/django-app/) to my friends so they could test it.

the Problem is - I use django's Dev server (python /path-to-django-app/manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT).

How do I make the devserver public?

EDIT:

Oh, there's something I forgot to mention. As I sad I use VMware with Ubuntu. I have a shellscript that returns me my current int-IP 192.168.xx.xx and saves it in a environment-variable ($CUR_IP)
So, each time I want to run django's devserver I simply execute

```
python /path-to-django-site/manage.py runserver $CUR_IP:8080
```

At this way I become an http-adress (e.g.http://192.168.40.145:8080/app-name/) which I CAN USE OUTSIDE my virtual machine. I could test it on my host (win7) machine. That's actually the reason why I asked the question. I thought there's a way to use the ext-IP and make runserver usable outside too

Comment: From what I remember of the Django docs, I think they state that the dev server hasn't been security tested so this is really isn't advisable. And as rebus says, it's single threaded, so performance under load will be shit. Best to use apache + plugins, or whatever.

Comment: The security and performance are NOT the big deal. The only thing I want is to show what I've made and how it looks like. There are currently only one or two persons whoe would be interested to see this primitive-crap at work =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`192.168.*.*` is a LAN-private address -- once you've done the proper VMWare (or other VM manager) and firewall incantations to make it accessible from the LAN, it still won't be accessible from outside the LAN, i.e., from the internet at large (a good thing too, because such development servers are *not* designed for security and scalability).

To make some port of a machine with a LAN-private IP visible to the internet at large, you need a router with a "virtual servers" ability (many routers, even cheap ones, offer it, but it's impossible to be specific about enabling it since each brand has its own idiosyncratic way).  I would also recommend [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) or other similar service to associate a stable DNS name to your always-varying public IP (unless you're splurging for a static IP from your connectivity provider, of course, but the latter option is becoming costlier all the time).

superuser.com or serverfault.com may provide better answers and details (once you give every single little detail of your configuration in a question) since the question has nothing much to do with software development and everything to do with server administration and configuration.

Answer (score 98):

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8181
```

This will [run development server](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#runserver-port-or-ipaddr-port) that should listen on all IP's on port 8181.

Note that as of [Jun 17, 2011 Django development](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ce165f7bbf) server is threaded by default [(ticket #1609)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16099).

From docs:

> Note that the default IP address,
>   127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To
>   make your development server viewable
>   to other machines on the network, use
>   its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1)
>   or 0.0.0.0.

Comment: so, the only way to do this is congifiguring apache, mod_py, etc ? Simple - use 'normal' web-server (apache, lighttp, etc) instead django's DevServer ?

Comment: I'd say it depends on number of developers, i work in small team and for showing off i do use development server, but if you have a need for many concurrent connections I'd suggest using real web server (we use [Apache and mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), [mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/?from=olddocs) is not maintained anymore.)

Comment: And, as of newer date, it seems [mod_python](http://modpython.org/) has been released in newer version

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have ruby installed, you just have to get localtunnel:

```
gem install localtunnel
```

then start your python development server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

in another shell, start localtunnel:

```
localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 8000
```

That will output an url to access your local server.

```
Port 8000 is now publicly accessible from http://xxxx.localtunnel.com
```

That's it.

Comment: gem install localtunnel gives this on Ubuntu 14.04: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'localtunnel' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: localone, rack-tunnel @trez

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04: `$ sudo npm install -g localtunnel`, start your python development server and then in another shell `$ lt --port 8000`. Source: http://localtunnel.me

Comment: It works well to follow @Moreno's update to this answer. For those who do not yet have npm, install https://nodejs.org/, and npm will be bundled with it. The combination of these sources constitutes the only truly complete solution I see on this page.

Comment: Do we need to perform port forwarding for this to work?

Answer (score 7):

I had to add this line to settings.py in order to make it work (otherwise it shows an error when accessed from another computer)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

then ran the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9595
```

Also, make sure that your firewall allows communication to the chosen port (9595 in this case)

Answer (score 4):

Already answered but adding npm alternate of same localtunnel

```
sudo npm install -g localtunnel

lt --port 8000 --subdomain yash
```

Comment: work like a charm. i run `./manage.py runserver 0:8000` and now the site is available in `localtunnel.me`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Virtualbox, You need to change the network setting in VB from "NAT" to "Bridged Adaptor". Then restart the linux. Now if you run `sudo ifconfig` you are able to see your IP address like `192.168.*.*` . The last step is runserver

`python manage.py runserver 192.168.*.*:8000`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure bridged networking in VMWare and also grant access to the target port in Ubuntu firewall.

Comment: Way bridged? I use NAT-settings and I'm able to access this IP from outside (curently only HOST)

Why(What for) should I configure ubuntu-firewall? Is it necessary to enable access from outside for other (non-host) machines ?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest trying something like `pyngrok` to programmatically manage an `ngrok` tunnel for you? Full disclosure, I am the developer of it. Django example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#django), but it's as easy as installing `pyngrok`:

```
pip install pyngrok
```

and using it:

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

# <NgrokTunnel: "http://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:8000">
http_url = ngrok.connect(8000)
```

No messing with ports or firewalls or IP addresses, and now you can also inspect the traffic (which is useful since what you're doing here is ongoing development, not running a `prod`-ready server).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [cotunnel](https://www.cotunnel.com), Just run cotunnel in your ubuntu (in VMware) change your tunnel port in cotunnel dashboard which port you are using in local side. It gives public url and you can share the url with your friends.

Your Django server can listen to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 (I prefer 0.0.0.0) it does not matter for cotunnel.