# change port in pydev

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

Hi everyone i'm trying to learn the django framework and I'm using PyDev (Eclipse Python Development Framework/Plugin). When I try to run my application I get an error:

```
Error: [Errno 10013]
```

I know that this is because of the port. I use the port 8000 and i want to change it to 8080. Does anyone knows what exactly should i do to change the port?

```
 pydev debugger: starting
 Validating models...

 0 errors found
 Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'muapp.settings'
 Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
 Error: [Errno 10013]
```

It might be useful to point out that PyDev, like Eclipse, runs the configured command when the `Run` button is pressed.  How is the default command and/or its options changed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pydev, but this might help. You need to replace something like `./manage.py runserver` with `./manage.py runserver 8080`.

Comment: thank you Alasdair for your your response. I know that but the problem is that i don't know how to do this in pydev.

Comment: Does this video help? http://vimeo.com/5027645. Skip about 14 minutes in. Then use `runserver 8080` instead of `runserver 8000` in the arguments.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll add the comment as an answer so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/5027645). Skip about 14 minutes in. Then use runserver 8080 instead of runserver in the arguments.

Comment: **Any** usful information that can be added is appreciated.  Simply   addink a vague link, however, might be useful as a comment.  What's the procedure to change the default `Run` command in Eclipse/PyDev? That's the question, rather than, "have a look at this video for my question".

Comment: @ILMostro_7 I agree that this answer could be clearer, but as I said I don't use pydev so I am not the person to improve it. You are very welcome to suggest edits to the answer to provide more details, or write an alternative answer. However I'd disagree with your description of the link as 'vague' -- it showed the OP what they needed to do, and solved their problem.

Comment: It's "vague" because it's a link, rather than "according to that link, you do this....".

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [PyDev Documentation](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html) on how to change the **Run** configuration.

Run/Debug as Django

> Run as Django/Debug as Django are available (note that they set the
>   --noreload by default).
>
> This will create a default Run configuration, so, you may edit it
>   later through run > run configurations (or debug > debug
>   configurations) if you want to change a parameter.
>
> Note: to know how to rerun the last launch see: the Rerun Last Launch
>   topic on PyDev Launching
>
> Note 2: if the --noreload is not passed, only the parent process will
>   be killed from Eclipse and the others will only be killed when they'd
>   be reloaded (i.e.: on a code-change).

Whether it's "Eclipse" or "PyDev", right-click on the Project and select "Run As" --> "Run Configurations..."

[image: Run Configuration]

Additionally, according to the [django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#runserver),

> runserver [addrport]¶
>
> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. By
>   default, the server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1. You
>   can pass in an IP address and port number explicitly.

Therefore, in your Project's **Run Configuration**, on the **Arguments** tab, simply add:

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

This should have the server listen on all interfaces/IPs.  Alternatively, you can make it more specific to your *public-facing* IP instead:

```
runserver 123.456.789.123:45678
```

Please, note that in this case, my IP would be "123.456.789.123" and the port would be "45678".

---

The following Answers might also be of use:

- [How to make Django's devserver public ? Is it generaly possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328926/how-to-make-djangos-devserver-public-is-it-generaly-possible)
- [How can i get the running server URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119149/how-can-i-get-the-running-server-url)
- [External Link; Third-party blog-post](http://www.holeintheceiling.com/blog/2012/06/21/django-and-runserver-0-0-0-0/)