# How can i get the running server URL

Tags: django

When i run the server it shows me a message http://127.0.0.1:8000/. I want to get the url in code. I dont have request object there.

Comment: In which code you want to get the URL?

Comment: Long time ago, but did you found the answer?

Answer (score 21):

```
request.build_absolute_uri('/')
```

or you could try

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: it gives me my machine IP. not the 127.0.0.1

Comment: breaks the server on django 2.1.4

Answer (score 21):

With Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host), You can use:

```
domain = request.get_host()
# domain = 'localhost:8000'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know exactly the IP address that the development server is started with, you can use `sys.argv` for this. The Django development server uses the same trick internally to restart the development server with the same arguments

Start development server:

```
manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Get address in code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import sys
    print sys.argv[-1]
```

This prints `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: nice one, I thought this should be possible, couldn't find the restart command :-)

Comment: The autoreload mechanism is in django.utils.autoreload. In the restart_with_reloader method, it takes its arguments from `sys.argv`

Comment: This answer definitely deserves more credit since it isnt dependent on a request being sent. Do you know if this works on a production server?

Comment: You should definitely manage the case where the command is run without argument: `manage.py runserver`.  You can simply use this: `print(sys.argv[-1] if sys.argv[-1] != 'runserver' else '127.0.0.1:8000')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
host = socket.gethostname()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import subprocess


def get_ip_machine():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    ip_regex = re.compile('(((1?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.){3}((1?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))')

    return ip_regex.search(process.stdout.read(), re.MULTILINE).group()
```