# Find which IP address was used by manage.py while the Django dev server was started

Tags: python, django

In Django dev environment, we start our Django server in various way, like:-

`python3 manage.py runserver` *which auto starts development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/*

OR

`python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:8005` *which auto starts development server at http://192.168.1.1:8005/*

How or in what ways, can I find the IP address that the development server was started using which IP address and which port number?

I want to write a python script within this Django project (in an app), which could tell me that the dev server is accessible on <`this_specific_ip_address`> (ex: 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) and then on <`this_specific_port_number`> (ex: 8000 or 8005).

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Find out the process ID and then use `psutil.Process(pid=xxx).cmdline()` to get the command and find if there's an IP different from 127.0.0.1 or not.

Comment: ok -- I can manually find the PID, but i am not sure how to have the script within Django Project app auto-find the PID -- could you give pointers please @Daviid

Comment: Here is a [dirty trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119663/11517893). You could improve it by adding a condition: `sys.argv[-1] if sys.argv[-1] != 'runserver' else '127.0.0.1:8000'`

Answer (score 0):

`Django` runs with the following py file:

`C:[...]\Django\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py`

You could edit the `def inner_run(self, *args, **options):` method and add any code that will run only when the server starts.

With the following addition, you can save the last IP address and port that the server runs on to a file.

```
        with open('C:\\file.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(
            (
                "Django version %(version)s, using settings %(settings)r\n"
                "Starting development server at %(protocol)s://%(addr)s:%(port)s/\n"

            )
            % {
                "version": self.get_version(),
                "settings": settings.SETTINGS_MODULE,
                "protocol": self.protocol,
                "addr": "[%s]" % self.addr if self._raw_ipv6 else self.addr,
                "port": self.port
            }
        )
```

**result: file.txt**

```
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'app.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

You could also write a log to a database.

Comment: What if we update Django ? We lose the custom code…