# How can I change django server's port number in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I have developed a simple application in **Eclipse & Django & Pydev**. The application fails while starting and I am given the following error:

```
*Error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions*
```

I have tried changing the port number to 8080 in Eclipse by changing the *Run Configurations*, but this has failed.

How can solve this problem and host my Django application on other port?

Comment: this question is answered here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826768/change-port-in-pydev)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do this outside of Eclipse, you can run the Django development server on a different port with

```
python manage.py runserver PORT_HERE
```

For example, to use port 8005, you can do

`python manage.py runserver 8005`

Comment: I have changed port this way but it did not have any effect. I think I should change port number in Eclipse , but I don't know how I can do