# React native fetch api does not work with localhost, IP, or even 10.0.2.2

Tags: android, django, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I am using expo client on my android device and  have setup up a django server at `localhost:8000` and i'm trying to access and endpoint using fetch in react native. I have looked at [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)  [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator) and [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips) but that did not work.

I also tried using my machine's ip address instead of localhost, but no results. Here is a sample code

```
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://my-ip-address:8000/restapi/')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("success")
        response = response.json()
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you testing on your device or simulator?

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 as your ip address. If that doesn't work try using postman to see if you can communicate.

Comment: I'm using my mobile device. I tried 127.0.0.1. That didn't work and also I used postman to verify that I'm getting the correct response

Comment: Using an actual device is a bit different. Based on the emulator links you gave, and using 10.0.2.2 I assumed you were using an emulator. Is your phone on the same network. Have you validated you don't have a firewall, or anything blocking incoming connections/port?

Comment: Just to be clear, "success" is not being printed in the console, correct? And you're using a local network address, and all devices in question are connected to the same network?

Comment: My phone is on the same wifi network. And I check my firewall for blocking connections. I will try and emulator and see if that works

Comment: Can your phone access the same url in a web browser?

Comment: Yes all the devices are on the same wi-fi network. And i'm not able to access the same url via my phone

Comment: If your phone's browser can't access the same url, it may be a django config issue. I'm not familiar with django, but [this may help make the django server accessible on your network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727/how-to-access-the-local-django-webserver-from-outside-world)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be an issue with the django configuration. Especially if your phone's web browser is unable to get the expected response as well.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---addrport):

```
Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines
on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the
network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).
```

See [How to access the local Django webserver from outside world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2260745/3495594), though the answer also applies on a local network:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

You can replace `0.0.0.0` with the machine's address if you know it.

---

Also worth noting in your response handler that `response.json()` returns a Promise, not JSON. Instead you want:

```
fetch('http://my-ip-address:8000/restapi/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to csum's answer, please check if the firewall has allowed remote access to your android device (device IP as remote) for the django server. If you've any anti-virus installed and controlling firewall, ensure that it has a rule in its firewall.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Acording to your code,

- your django's port : `:8080`
- your fetch's target port: `:8000`

Check again. 
And I recommend using [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) when you test your server apis.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The port is 8000