# How I can count the video views in django by ip for Anonymous users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I created a view to get the Anonymous users IP, I want when this user what the video then register this ip has watched the video,I know it's now efficient because might the user use diffrent network,

This my model of the user by ip:

```
class UsersByIP(models.Model):
  ip_user = models.GenericIPAddressField()
  def __str__(self):
     return self.ip_user
```

This model to make relationship between the vdeo and the number of viewrs by ip

```
class Video(models.Model):
     viewers_by_ip = models.ManyToManyField(UsersByIP, default='192.168.0.1', blank=True)
```

I created this view to register the ip as view but I got this error:

`Field 'id' expected a number but got '127.0.0.1'`

and I couldn't solv it.

The view:

```
       num_views_by_ip = Video.objects.annotate(
                num_views_ip=Count('viewers_by_ip'),
            ).order_by('-viewers_by_ip')
            data = get_object_or_404(num_views_by_ip, pk=pk)
            ip_user = UsersByIP(ip_user=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                __, created = Video.viewers_by_ip.through.objects.get_or_create(
                    video=data,
                    usersbyip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                )

                if created:
                    data.num_views_by += 1
```

I would like to get any suggestions to solve this view or make a new view (logic)

Comment: It is storing `ip of Device` or `id of internet provider` or `ip of site` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to specify the model `UsersByIP` this way `usersbyip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')` but `usersbyip` expects either the id of the model or the model instance itself **not** a field of the model. You should pass it the `ip_user` variable of yours (after making sure it is saved):

```py
ip_user, created = UsersByIP.objects.get_or_create(ip_user=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    __, created = Video.viewers_by_ip.through.objects.get_or_create(
        video=data,
        usersbyip=ip_user
    )
```

Comment: Thank you sir this work fine with me, you are life saver

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat - It is storing `ip of Device` or `id of internet provider` or `ip of site` ?

Comment: @Progam that really depends on the use. If there are proxies in between `REMOTE_ADDR` will give the last proxy and not the user.  there is also `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` which can be used. To be able to get the user's IP address reliably it is best to use some 3rd party package that knows what it is doing, for eg: [django-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware)

Comment: I think the `ip of device` will be **127.0.0.1:8000** in local host. Am i right ? Then how someone can test it in local host ?

Comment: @Progam this question ([How to access the local Django webserver from outside world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727/how-to-access-the-local-django-webserver-from-outside-world)) would be helpful for you if you want to test this