# Django project is not running on browser

Tags: python, django, docker

I am following a basic django project, mainly so I can see it run on the browser, because I have another django project where it says it runs on `http//127.0.0.1:8000/` but on my browser it shows errors.
I am working linode in cmd on windows laptop, I have edited my firewall on linode to allow ssh, http and https.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

this is the tutorial I am following.

[image: my code]

This is what my code says in cmd.

[image: the browser]

This is what my browser says.

Comment: Try localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial assumes your test server is running on the same machine; `127.0.0.1` is a shorthand for it. Your server is actually running on linode, so you need two things:

- expose the server interface outside, as 127.0.0.1 is only accessible internally. The command is: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727) for more details.
- access it by the remote machine IP/hostname and expose server on external interface. So, in your browser, instead of `127.0.0.1:8000`, use `<linode_machine_IP>:8000`